# Collect data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I´m trying to get the price value out but I can not get it, it always return a "-".

I want it to return the 1,376,000

**HTML**

---

```
<span class="price_big_right">
    <span id="pc-lowest-1" data-price="1,376,000">
        1,376,000 
        <img alt="c" class="coins_icon_l_bin" src="https://example.com/123"/>
    </span>
</span>
```

Here is what I´m trying to do

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib

URL = 'https://www.futbin.com/22/player/426'
def test():

    page = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    price = soup.find(id="pc-lowest-1").get_text()


# price
print(price)

test()
```

Comment: check the html source, not the web tools: this is what you get with requests and `pc-lowest-1` has nothing but a hyphen in it. go to the network tab, filter xhr, and you get this link https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player=20801&rids=50352449,67129665 `player` is player id, and `rids` are the rare ids

Comment: there is a way i can get the info in that link using the first link ? (https://www.futbin.com/22/player/426) without searching manually ?

Comment: i told you how to: first one is player id search for `ID 20801` on the info box. the rids are the rare cards `91` and `92` above the pic search the id in the code. i think you know how to do it

Comment: i did not explain my self that well.
Is there a python function so I can get from https://www.futbin.com/22/player/426 the XHR link ?

Comment: i gave you a link: you look how it's formed and you mimic it with the info you scraped on the page

Comment: I know you gave me the link but can i get the link with a python function so i can reply it for multiple links (10000 different pages)

Comment: yes and i keep telling you how to do it and you don't get it

Comment: my question is:
is that any way to get the link without using the browser or going to the network tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in this page is being loaded by JavaScript. So `beautifulsoup` will not work. You have to use `selenium` to get the data.

However, if you see under the Network tab in Chrome DevTools, the page loads the data from the below end point.

```
https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player=20801&rids=50352449,67129665
```

You can directly make a request to this end point and the fetch the data.

Here is how you can do it.

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player=20801&rids=50352449,67129665'

page = requests.get(URL)
x = page.json()
data = x['20801']['prices']
print(data['pc']['LCPrice'])
```

```
1,349,000
```

Comment: thats perfect but can it be automated ? 
Let me explain it, i want the same value for the https://www.futbin.com/22/player/426 from player 0 to 15000, so there is a simple way to get the new url you gave me ?